# How do you get a loop to stop when an array runs out of values in python?

Tags: python, arrays, random

I am working on a game of bingo for which I am using an array with 75 numbers. After rolling a number the code will remove it. I want to stop rolling numbers when there are no numbers left in the array.

So far I have this:

```
import random
numbers=[]
number=1
for i in range (0,75):
    numbers.append(number)
    number=number+1
```

How do I get the code to stop rolling a number when the array runs out of numbers?

Comment: You might want to explain your problem better. In your code I don't see an array (or a list) that could run out of numbers.

Comment: "if numbers:"  will work for you, the empty list will be behaved as false

Comment: First of all I would expect you to fill your array with random numbers. Currently you do not yet do that. Then pick out a number with a random index from range (len (array))(isn't that how bingo works?) and use e.g. the list's remove method to remove it. You can use a simple for loop, since you know in advance how many times you'll have to delete a number. But is that really the assignment? Bingo for 1 person is a bit dull, since you always win.

Comment: "I want to stop rolling numbers when there are no numbers left in the array." That's like saying "While there are numbers left in the array, roll a number and remove it." And that is practically Ahsanul Haque's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `random` function to mix up the outcomes.
You can then use create a sequence which then allows you to pick them in order.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `random` to shuffle your elements, then pick them in order:

```
import random
numbers = list(range(1,76))
random.shuffle(numbers)

while len(numbers) > 0:
  number = numbers.pop()
  print(number)
```

Comment: `while numbers` should be enough in place of `while len(numbers) > 0`.

Comment: And, you actually picking them not in order, you are picking in reverse order. (Just for clarification)

Comment: @AhsanulHaque: how is this in reverse order? There is no order because the `numbers` list is _random_ to begin with, so it makes no difference whether the numbers are popped from the front or the back. This method is more efficient than using `list.remove()` to remove a specific value from the list.

Comment: @mhawke, I emphasized on  `then pick them in order` part. He had a list after shuffle. And, then he was picking elements from right to left. Am I wrong? Of course, as a whole there is no order.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque `while len(numbers) > 0` is clearer to someone who isn't familiar with Python's idiosyncrasies.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque: OK I see what you meant. But I think that _lovasoa_ simply intended "in order" to mean pop from the list.

Comment: @tom: that's not an idiosyncrasy. Truth value testing is a Python idiom, and is generally preferred.

Comment: @mhawke: An idiosyncrasy can be an idiom :) But you are right, can't argue with [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

```
import random

current_list = list(range(0,75))

while current_list:
    value = random.choice(current_list)
    print("Current Value is {}".format(value))
    current_list.remove(value)
```

Comment: Or *numbers*, since that's what the OP calls it.

Comment: Quite logical ... fixed.

Comment: This only works in Python 2, where `range()` returns a list. In Python 3, `range(0, 75)` returns a special object which behaves like the list `[0,1,...,74]` but can't be modified, so `remove()` will fail.

Comment: @tom, Yes in python3, it will throw `AttributeError: 'range' object has no attribute 'remove'` . I assumed this is python2, but I shouldn't do that, as OP didn't mention. Fixed.

Comment: This has a complexity of O(N²), whereas it can be done in O(N)

Comment: @lovasoa: When N=75, the difference is moot ;)